# cURL request in jenkins pipeline with hidden token and key

Tags: curl, jenkins, sh, access-token, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to find a better way to run a remote jenkins job using curl requests.

My current pipeline setup is as follows:

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    build 'erp_load'
  },
    secondBranch: {
    build 'erp_load2'
  },
    thirdBranch: {
    build 'erp_load3'
  }
  failFast: true

node {
    sh 'curl -X POST http://user:xxxkeyxxx@remote_host.com/job/flow_one/build?token=\'xxxtokenxxx\''
}
```

But I want to find a better way to do this cURL request without having to explicitly write my token and keys in it.

One way I am now doing is to build a python script that calls my credentials library and runs a shell command using the os module like this:

```
import os
import credentials

os.system('curl -X POST http://user:{0}@remote_host.com/job/flow_one/build?\
token=\'{1}\''.format(credentials.key,credentials.token))
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do this directly in jenkins without compromising the key and token elements of the call, and without using an additional workflow like a script in python.

Comment: You can use the `withCredentials` step, and Jenkins will make a "best effort" to at least hide them from the build logs.

Comment: Ok, with "withCredentials"  hides it from the log, but is it safe enough?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "safe enough".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins withCredentials secret not working with shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63966168/jenkins-withcredentials-secret-not-working-with-shared-library)