# Jenkins withCredentials secret not working with shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I started developing a solution for jenkins shared library but getting odd exception while using the withCredentials pluging for a secret. i did not have any issue with withcredentials for username password or for secrets while used them  in jenkins pipeline. but when implementing for shared library it is giving me error which i cannot resolve yet.

**Code**

```
def scanProject(String[] inputs) {
        script.echo "inside scanProject.."
        try {

                    String version= ''
                    String projectName = '' 
                    String environment = ''
                    
                    this.script.withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'sonarqube.test.service', variable: 'pass')]) {
    
                         this.script.sh "echo {this.script.env.pass}"
                    }


                } catch(error) {
                ...
```

this sonarqube.test.service is a secret text

**error**

```
inside constructor..
[Pipeline] echo
inside scanProject..
[Pipeline] echo
Exception happened during SonarQube scanning. Find the message below:
[Pipeline] echo
No signature of method: com.example.sonarqube.SonarQubeScan.string() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:sonarqube.test.service, variable:pass]]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), find(), sprintf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: Have you tried just this.script.sh "echo $pass"?

Comment: tried.. but didn't work. i have updated what worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me the below way worked

```
this.script.withCredentials([script.string(credentialsId: 'sonarqube.test.service', variable: 'pass')]) {

       this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-4.0.0.1744-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=${this.script.pass} -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..
                    
                    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works and i use it actually. Nevertheless in this context i haven't found a way yet to fulfill the security issue, if i have to use variables and credentials in the bat or sh script. Please keep this in mind.

> A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which
> is insecure. Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s):
> [pass] See
> https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.

for

```
version = '4.0.0.1744'
this.script.withCredentials([script.string(credentialsId: 'sonarqube.test.service', variable: 'pass')]) {

       this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-${version}-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=${this.script.pass} -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..              
          
}
```

The same issue will affect with:

```
   this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-${version}-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=" + this.script.pass + " -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..
```

These workarounds don't work, too:

```
   this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-${version}-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=\${this.script.pass} -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..
   this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-${version}-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=\$this.script.pass -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..
   this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-${version}-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=" + '${this.script.pass}' + " -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..
   this.script.sh "/root/sonar-scanner-${version}-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=" + '$this.script.pass' + " -Dsonar.projectName="+projectName+" ..
```

In this case the sh-script uses the variable name **this.script.pass** instead of the value of the variable.